# People in the next room in my hotel are having noisy sex; I can't sleep! What to do?

Tags: hotels, etiquette, sex

The people in the next room are having sex all night! it is early morning and I can not sleep and my flight is in a few hours! Their bed is hitting the wall because of the action which makes a great noise in my room like someone is constantly knocking on the door. I tried calling the reception but nothing happened, then tried calling their room but the phone is on DND. I always liked hotels as a part of travel, just not this time!

Should I knock the door and try something like "please stop [expletive deleted] or I will join you!?"

Comment: Get earplugs...

Comment: @gerrit at this time? I don't think I can. It's just not fair, I can't sleep and can't join them...

Comment: Next time you're travelling, don't forget your earplugs.

Comment: I'd knock on the door and ask if I can join in. :)

Comment: @HaLaBi Sure but if I have fly somewhere I'll pass. ;).  I remember hearing my neighbors in the morning through the concrete wall. :)

Comment: Bang on the wall (maybe in syncopation to their bed sounds).

Comment: Can't add an answer, but when you call reception and they are unable to quiet your neighbors, ask them to move you to another room.  Inconvenient, but you should be able to sleep, and it'll only cost you 30 minutes to move.  If they can't move you, ask for a refund or comp - they are not providing you with what you paid for - a good night's sleep.

Comment: Provide loud commentary?

Comment: Play loud Buddhist music.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not ask the front desk to get you a new room? We were once put in a room right next to the elevator shaft once and didn’t notice until we shut off the tv before bed. The elevator clattering was the most annoying sound imaginable. We tried to bear with it for an hour but just couldn’t get any shut-eye as every time our eyes would get heavy, the elevator would move and the cables would clatter and clang against the wall right by the bed.

We went to the front desk. Even though it was past 11p, we got a new room and a complimentary breakfast coupon with apologies.

You can even ask the front desk if you can keep your unpacked stuff in the old room overnight and use the new room just for sleeping until you can bring your luggage over the next day. They won’t be able to rent out your old room anyway so it’d be something a good front desk staff person would be able to do. I remembered their name and slipped them a good tip the next day.

Answer (score 28):

I believe, all jokes aside, you have four options:

1. Try to ignore it. Obviously, you're trying this already and it's not working. But you could turn the tv on, listen to some music, or take a sleeping tablet if you have one.
2. Passive aggressive behaviour.  Turn the tv or music up really loudly.  Bang on the wall. Hope they'll take the hint.  Cheer them on!  Decide to take delight in exacting  your own form [of personal revenge on your neighbours](http://www.roundtheworldflights.com/rtw-blogs/index.php/talking-rtw/neighbours.html).  Order them some food!
3. Indirect/Direct confrontation. You could yell at them to shut up, that people are trying to sleep, but I've seen this be ignored even in dorms.  You could go around to their room (since you've tried the phone) and knock on the door, and explain the situation and that they're being unreasonably loud - they may not even realise that the sound is carrying that well!
   [image]
   *(from [homesandproperty.co.uk](http://asset2.homesandproperty.co.uk/handp/media/noisy_neighbours_350_10320.jpg))*
4. Use the resources available to you in a nice hotel - call reception.  Tell them that you called before and nothing happened, that it's still going on and that they're banging on the wall (you don't need to say what you think is happening, just that the effect is keeping you up), and will they please send someone to knock on the door and tell them there's been a complaint.

More than likely, 3 and 4 are your best bets for a quick response, and #4 is the most likely to keep you calm - a bad confrontation while you're overtired (ala #3) may not be the best thing for you.

Comment: The user already said that the 4th option didn't work :P

Comment: @Noldor130884 I was merely listing the options, future readers might want to try them all.

Answer (score 10):

Well you can always do "The Thin Wall Challenge":

### - [Thin Wall Challenge](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9PITBODSCk)

I guess it can keep you busy while you wait for them to finish. Or you can call reception and tell them that it seems someone is being attacked on the other room because of all the screaming ;). That worked me one or two times...

Comment: The link is broken.